# How to reference at a parent class selector some levels up to add a variation?

Tags: css, sass

How to add a variant class .navbar-dark to .navbar from the child class .dropdown-toggle by SASS?

I try to achieve this:

.nav-wrapper .navbar.navbar-dark .nav-item > .nav-link.dropdown-toggle

```
.nav-wrapper{
  .navbar {
    $navbar: #{&};

    .nav-item{
      > .nav-link{

        &.dropdown-toggle{

          @at-root #{$navbar}.navbar-dark & {
            background-color: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
.nav-wrapper .navbar.navbar-dark .nav-wrapper .navbar .nav-item > .nav-link.dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: red;
}
```

And

```
.nav-wrapper{
  .navbar {
    $navbar: #{&};

    .nav-item{
      > .nav-link{

        &.dropdown-toggle{

          @at-root #{$navbar}.navbar-dark {
            background-color: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
.nav-wrapper .navbar.navbar-dark {
  background-color: red;
}
```